# How to read in an xls file after using unzip() to place it into a temporary folder?

Tags: r, xls, zip, readxl

I receive weekly emails from a database as zip files. In the zip file is a single xls file. When I use unzip() and place the xls file into a designated shared network directory, I cannot use any xls read functions to actually access and manipulate the data (I haven't tried read.xls because of the Perl dependencies, but I'm willing to if there are no other options).

I've tried every Excel reader I can find.

```
read_xls(unzip(zipfile = zfile, files = "Data Extract.xls", exdir = "~\\Excel Files"))
```

Errors include the following where I would simply expect a dataframe output:

"libxls error: Unable to open file"

"Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file 'Data.zip:F'

EDIT: It turns out that despite the DB interface calling this file within the zip an .xls file, it's an HTML file and readHTMLTable() from library(XML) did the trick just fine. Thank you for the questions which lead me to looking at ths issue from a different angle.

Comment: Have you checked whether the file is corrupted? Were you able to open that unzipped file using Excel?

Comment: @aivanov... Thanks for the suggestion, but yes. I have tried that.

Comment: From your error, I think this is all about the `unzip`ping, not the reading of the excel file. I tried creating a zip file from an xls file, and it unzipped just fine. I then renamed that zip file to `file.zip:F` (as you show in your error), and it failed. Try making sure the filename actually ends in `.zip` and not `.zip:F` (will involve `file.rename(...)` and maybe some regex if the `:F` is not constant).

Comment: @Banjerin'Foo' were you able to open that file successfully using MS Excel?

Comment: Banjerin'Foo', does running `unzip(...)` without `read_xls` produce errors or warnings?

Comment: @aivanov I should amend my reply to you. I can open the file using MS Excel, but I do get the following message first, so you may have a point there: 

"The file format and extension of 'Data File.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Comment: @r2evans I do not get any errors from the unzip() function. I do get a warning message in Excel, but the file does open: "The file format and extension of 'Data File.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Lastly, the ":F" is not a part of the file name. That is only included in the error message. I believe that is relative to the network drive, "F:", that I'm sending the unzipped file to.